# How do I post a gif to Facebook and Twitter using the gif url

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm working on a app that creates GIFs and then gives the user the ability to post socially. I was looking at the structure of the url posts on [GIFY](http://giphy.com/) and I'm trying to emulate them. ( for instance

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[GIFURL]

http://twitter.com/share?url=[GIFURL]

but it only seems to work for GIFY urls. What am I doing wrong? is their a way to format the GIF url so it will actually appear in the facebook url or tweet? I've tried using gifs hosted on both Parse and Amazon S3 and neither work.